# Don't understand this error: initializing argument 1 of 'class' [with T = unsigned int]' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

this is the first of my 3 errors appearing when building in Eclipse.

In the main function I'm just instantiating the class multidimensional_vector<1,  unsigned int> which is a  template.

Strangely when I change the argument w in push_back() in line 14 to *w the errors are disappearing. But I just read that it's not ok to push_back pointers so I wonder if it's ok to use *w as an argument for push_back() instead?

The code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
using std::vector;

enum Foo { length = 4, heigth = 4};

template<unsigned int dimcount, typename T>
class multidimensional_vector
{
    private: vector< multidimensional_vector<dimcount-1, T> > wector;
    public:
    multidimensional_vector() {}
    multidimensional_vector(T a) {
        for (int var = 0; var <= heigth; ++var) {
            multidimensional_vector<dimcount-1,  T> *w = new multidimensional_vector<dimcount-1,  T>(a);
            wector.push_back(w);
        }
    }

    T getValue(vector<unsigned int> v){
        return wector[v[dimcount]].getValue(v);
    }

    void setValue(vector<unsigned int> v, T value){
        wector[v[dimcount]].setValue(v, value);
    }
};

template<typename T>
class multidimensional_vector<0,T>
{
    private: T value;
    public:
    multidimensional_vector() {}
    multidimensional_vector(T a) {
        value = a;
    }

    T getValue(vector<unsigned int> v){
        return value;
    }

    void setValue(vector<unsigned int> v, T value){
        this->value = value;
    }
};



int main() {
    multidimensional_vector<1,  unsigned int> *nimarray = new multidimensional_vector<1,  unsigned int>(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message, and what line does it point to?

Comment: Wouldn't you be calling a copy constructor that doesn't exist?

Comment: Not related to your compiler error, but `wector.push_back(*w)` leaks memory. You `new`'d an object, then *copied* it into the vector, and never `delete`d it. To fix this, don't use `new` in the first place. `wector.emplace_back(a);` would be simpler.

Comment: @M.M You mean it should be wector.emplace_back(new multidimensional_vector<dimcount-1,  T>(a));? Can you please tell me how you are doing the grey background behind your code segments in the comment section?

Comment: no, stop using `new`.  Use backticks to highlight code. `   `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to compile the code fragment from the question, the only error reported by gcc 5.3.1 is:

```
t.C:12:34: error: ‘heigth’ was not declared in this scope
         for (int var = 0; var <= heigth; ++var) {
```

gcc does not report any error of the kind you are asking about.

After manually adding the declaration of this variable to the class, the given code compiles without any issues.

Except for the missing class member declaration, there's absolutely nothing wrong with the given code.

Comment: "there's absolutely nothing wrong with the given code." - it seems to me there are a lot of problems in the code, which won't give compilation errors

Comment: Sure, but the answer is limited to the question's domain, which is just compilation errors.

Comment: Yes I removed the enum because when posting here, I forgot I still am using the heigth. Also I changed the *w back to w, so it should be the version now which isn't working, sorry.

Comment: @M.M Hello, thanks for your answers, could you plase check the updated code again, as it was ment to be? I wonder if only the push_back is a problem. Also you hinted there are lots of problems, maybe we could talk in private I'm curious and eager to learn. :)

Comment: Your "wector" container contains "multidimensional_vector<dimcount-1, T>" objects, but you're trying to push_back() a pointer to this class. That's your error, and I'm sure that this is exactly what the compiler error message is telling you, if you slowly read it. When you have a "std::vector<X>", you can only push_back() "X" objects into the vector, not "X *". You don't need to allocate a pointer to the object on the heap, just declare "multidimensional_vector<dimcount-1,  T> w(a);" before the push_back().

Comment: ... but if you really want to store pointers in your vector, you can do that too, but you will then also need to update every reference to the contents of the vector to reflect the fact that this is now a pointer, instead of a class instance. Additionally you will have to worry about memory leaks as well. Welcome to C++.